# for loop help and storing expression results

Tags: java

completely new to java and struggling with my assignments, I don't just want to ask for answers but the tutors are not even giving me the methods to use to write my code so I am struggling.

the advice given to me is to tidy up the formatting of the code so all the lines are either at the same level or cascade in one direction. needless to say this did no help.

I feel I am close, but might benefit from a push in the right direction.

the question is: In this part you will write a public method calculateCheckNumber() to find S and then use the expression given in part (d) to find C. The method should first create a string omitting the last digit of the longNumber and then find S by iterating through this string. (You may choose to do a separate iteration for the odd and even indexes, or you could do both in a single loop.)
Finally, your method should calculate and return the value of C using the expression given in (d). Choose meaningful identifiers for your variables.

Expression:
Check that the long number has exactly 16 digits. If not, the long number is not valid.

If the long number has 16 digits, drop the last digit from the long number, as this is the "check digit" that we want to check against.

Multiply by 2 the value of each digit starting from index 0 and then at each even index. In each case, if the resulting value is greater than 9, subtract 9 from it. Leave the values of the digits at the odd indexes unchanged.

Add all the new values derived from the even indexes to the values at the odd indexes and call this S.

Find the number that you would have to add to S to round it up to the next highest multiple of 10. Call this C. If C equals the check digit, then the long number could be valid.

```
    public class CreditCardChecker
    {
      // Variable for long numbers to be checked
      public String longNumber;
      public int checkDigit;
      public int checkSum;
      public int evenNumber;

      /**
       * Constructor for objects of class CreditCardChecker
       * including long number
      */
       public CreditCardChecker(String longNumber)
       {
       // initialise long number variable
       this.longNumber=longNumber;
       this.checkDigit=checkDigit;
       this.checkSum=checkSum;
       }
       /**
        * Sets the value of long number
       */
       public void setLongNumber(String aLongNumber)
       {
        this.longNumber=aLongNumber;
       }
      /**
       * method to get the long number
       */
        public String getLongNumber()
       {
        return this.longNumber;
       } 
      /**
       * method to check that long number has exactly 16 digits
       */    
       public boolean isCorrectLength()
      {
       if (longNumber.length() == 16)
      {
       return (true);
      }
       else
      {
       return (false);
      }
     }
      /**
       * Method to get the first 15 characters of long number
       */
        public String firstFifteen()
       {
        return longNumber.substring(0, 15);
       }
     /**
      * Method to calculate the check number from the long number
      */
       public int calculateCheckNumber()

      { 
       int checkSum=longNumber.charAt(15);
       evenNumber = Integer.parseInt(longNumber);
       for(int longNumber=0; longNumber<= 15; longNumber++){
       System.out.println(evenNumber);
       if (evenNumber %2==0)
        return (evenNumber *2);
     
       if (evenNumber>=9)
        return (evenNumber-9);
        checkSum = evenNumber + evenNumber++;
       }
         return this.evenNumber;
     }

    }
```

Comment: You should start using your TAB key. Then please stop putting `{`s on new lines, that's not Java convention. Check out [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_java_formatter.htm) site and [this](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) PDF.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve. Please can you be more explicit?

Comment: Hi, i need to take the String long number, take the first 15 characters, get the even index from the 15 characters, then - even index *2 (if the result is over 10 i need to -9 from those to get a single digit number) then add all the 15 characters together after changing the even index numbers.

Comment: @akuzminykh uh-oh, are you going to start a brace-and-indent-style religious war? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2715/3767 "The nice thing about standards is that there are so many of them to choose from."

Comment: *"needless to say this did no help"* - It helps.  It helps other people read your code.  Indeed when you get more experience, you will find it helps >>you<< read your own code.

Comment: @StephenP Don't worry, make peace, not war. But for Java it's definitely convention to not put `{`s on new lines. If you don't want to call it convention, then call it "it's the most common by far". Most, if not all, core libraries are written with `{`s on the same lines. Literaly all (serious) code and libraries I've seen do that in Java. This war is fought in C/C++ mostly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
package com.kickstart;

public class CreditCardChecker {
    /**
     * Variables
     */
    public String longNumber;
    public int checkDigit;
    public int checkSum;
    public int evenNumber;

    /**
     * Constructor for initializing objects of class CreditCardChecker
     */
    public CreditCardChecker(String longNumber, int checkDigit, int checkSum, int evenNumber) {
        this.longNumber = longNumber;
        this.checkDigit = checkDigit;
        this.checkSum = checkSum;
        this.evenNumber = evenNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Getters
     */
    public int getCheckDigit() {
        return checkDigit;
    }

    public int getCheckSum() {
        return checkSum;
    }

    public int getEvenNumber() {
        return evenNumber;
    }
    
    public String getLongNumber() {
        return longNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Setters
     */
    public void setEvenNumber(int evenNumber) {
        this.evenNumber = evenNumber;
    }

    public void setCheckSum(int checkSum) {
        this.checkSum = checkSum;
    }

    public void setCheckDigit(int checkDigit) {
        this.checkDigit = checkDigit;
    }

    public void setLongNumber(String longNumber) {
        this.longNumber = longNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Method to check that long number has exactly 16 digits and if character are only digits.
     * @return true if lenght of string is 16 and contains only digits, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isCorrectLength() {
        return getLongNumber().length() == 16 && getLongNumber().matches("[0-9]+");
    }

    /**
     * Method multiplies every even number by two and checks if $result is more than 10, if true $result - 9
     * otherwise just append number to StringBuilder
     * @return String of length 16
     */
    public String everyEvenNumberIsMultipliedBy2(){
        // You can use any variable here you want to append results {String, Integer, etc.}
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        // Method described on line n. 56
        if(isCorrectLength()){
            // For loop through String "longNumber"
            for(int i = 0; i < getLongNumber().length(); i++){
                // When character on index of "i" from for loop is an Odd number
                if(Character.getNumericValue(getLongNumber().charAt(i)) % 2 == 0){
                    // We multiplicity number by two and check if number is more than 10
                    if((Character.getNumericValue(getLongNumber().charAt(i)) * 2) > 10)
                        // If so we do on number minus nine and write it to our "result" variable
                        result.append(Character.getNumericValue(getLongNumber().charAt(i)) * 2 - 9);
                    else
                        // Otherwise we just append it to result without modifying
                        result.append(getLongNumber().charAt(i));
                } else
                    // So we do here. I could write this better (we do repetition on this line and line n. 85), but I wanted you to understand what is happening here
                    result.append(getLongNumber().charAt(i));

            }
        }
        // We return "result" which is of type StringBuilder so we parse it to String
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

This is Main class. You create an object of class "CreditCardChecker" here and use methods implemented in class.

Note that package name is mine. You have your own coresponding on created project. You will have to edit package path.

```
package com.kickstart;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CreditCardChecker creditCardChecker = new CreditCardChecker("1234567891234567", 2, 10, 2);

    // Note that all did all you asked in questing in comment. You will have to implement other methods as checkSum, etc. Or create new question.
            System.out.println(creditCardChecker.getLongNumber().length());
            System.out.println(creditCardChecker.getLongNumber());
        System.out.println(creditCardChecker.everyEvenNumberIsMultipliedBy2().length());
        System.out.println(creditCardChecker.everyEvenNumberIsMultipliedBy2());

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i need to take the String long number, take the first 15 characters, get the even index from the 15 characters, then - even index *2 (if the result is over 10 i need to -9 from those to get a single digit number) then add all the 15 characters together after changing the even index numbers.

Comment: @CraigBeverley Note that I should not be implementing your assignment. You can still improfe code. Have a look at seeter and getters you dont need them all, so you can delete ones you are not using and so on.

Comment: this is fantastic, thank you for helping me understand it, so to put the indexes into a result it is the stringBuilder command? and we don't have to assign it a variable?

Comment: @CraigBeverley This is a class called "CreditCardChecker". In... I will provide Main class to show you how to use an object of class. You are lucky I did not delede it yet.